# 404 error on clicking job link on springbatch admin ui

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am new to springbatch. I am trying to create a batch application and integrate   with batch admin ui. Versions I used are spring-batch-2.2.7 and spring-batch-admin-1.3.0.M1. I am able to run my job using junit and also able to see all my jobs on admin ui. When i click on the job, I am getting 404 error.

```
Home Page - 
http://myServer/ApplicationName
List of jobs link - 
http://myServer/ApplicationName/batch/jobs

When i click on the job link url is missing 'batch' in the url.
http://myServer/ApplicationName/jobs/JOBNAME

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue? Thanks!
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the 1.3.0 release version of spring batch admin ( http://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-batch-admin-1-3-0-release-is-available ). This should work now with current spring batch versions (2.2.x and 3.0.x). I tested this successfully with spring batch version 3.0.1.

There is also a good starting point for configuring spring batch admin together with spring boot: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot-2/